# Xcode 9 issues after cloning repo

Tags: ios, xcode

This is an app I'm helping out with remotely. I have some issues right after cloning repo..

1. Assets folder is marked as modified. `git status` results: `modified: AppName/Resources/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json`. One of many compile warnings says "A 1024x1024 app store icon is required for iOS apps". Is new 1024x1024 asset placeholder the modification that was made?
2. Many warnings:

[image]

The app is running well in App Store and has support for iPhoneX, so if I clone, shouldn't all this stuff be sorted out already? I still see layout issues when I run in simulator on any device size that were apparently fixed for iphoneX compatibility. When I was running Xcode 8.3 I didn't have these issues.

I need to add a feature, push and make build available on TestFlight, but I'm worried about pushing with all these compile errors & bet it wont even archive with missing 1024x1024 asset.

**Question**:
Should I just go back to previous version of Xcode rather than sticking with 9.1 or resolve all this stuff myself? Devs aren't really available for me to consult with since initial app was developed through full-service software dev company.
Im mainly in contact with business ops/project managers who don't really have knowledge of tech at this level. Im no seasoned dev myself so I'd like some advice here before expressing concerns with managers or getting strings pulled to talk with devs who last worked on it.

I'm hoping the first comment isn't that this question doesn't belong here. I think its a fine line.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with cloning or git. Cloning didn't create these issues; reality created them. If the app has issues, fix them. Isn't that your job? For example, a 1024x1024 app store icon _is_ required. So if you're going to "help out", shouldn't you add it? You didn't have that issue before because it wasn't required before. But it is now.

Comment: @matt  The point is that support was already added for iPhoneX, which could only be accomplished with Xcode 9.0 + right? So cloning the project shouldn't still present these issues.  A 1024x1024 should already exist otherwise app wouldn't be in app store. running app shouldn't still display layout issues that were fixed. Which makes me second guess if  I have proper source code. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I agree, but isn't that something you would have to work out with whoever you got this repo from? If they have checked in and used code that they didn't put onto the main branch, they need to tell you what branch it's on so you can switch to that branch. We can't tell you that. But for sure git is not breaking your project or anything. So there's nothing here that you need our help with.

Comment: You're right. I have meeting later on today so I'll at least be confident that my questions/concerns are valid. Unfortunate that there aren't any in-house frontend devs readily available.

Comment: There are really only three possibilities I can think of: (1) The iPhone X support wasn't added; (2) it was added in another branch (did you look in all the branches?); (3) it was added but never checked into the repo at all.

Comment: Sure enough there is a iPhoneXSupport branch. I will check it out. That would be odd if that branch was never merged with master though.

Comment: Not necessarily. I work in a Swift 4 branch on my apps that never moved back onto master. There are no laws about these things.

Comment: @matt I've gone through all the branches and none have iPhone X support, nor do they contain 1024x1024 icon. Each time I checkout a new branch the image/assets folder automatically gets marked as modified.

Comment: Well, my conclusions don't change. Either no 1024x1024 icon was ever included in the asset catalog (because that requirement is new; we used to upload the 1024x1024 icon separately), or it was included and the upload to iTunes Connect was performed but that change was never check into the repo, and so it was lost to history. However, I don't see what the big deal is: obtain the icon (if it isn't in the project elsewhere already) and add it to the asset catalog.

Comment: "When I was running Xcode 8.3 I didn't have these issues." Well, for the 1024x1024 icon, that's because Xcode 9 _introduced_ the requirement that this icon be in the asset catalog, rather than being uploaded separately as in the past. So that datum adds nothing to our understanding of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The app in the appstore could be submitted and released to the appstore with issues listed in the issue navigator of the xcode on posted screenshot.

So, switching to a version of Xcode which was used for a last submit to the app store by previous developers does not guarantee that those issues will be not present.

There is only one issue which you have to resolve is "1024x1024 app store icon is required for iOS app" and this can be done only within Xcode 9